# What Conditions Cause a Web Application to Be Just In Time Compiled?

Tags: asp.net, jit

**I'm curious as to the exact conditions that cause an application to be Just In-Time Compiled?**

I think we all know the first visit to a non pre-compiled site will cause a JIT. 
What about throwing new code into the App_Code directory?

I'm pretty sure some actions like saving the web.config simply cause the cause the Application Pool to unload and so far I'm a little confused as to which action has which result.

I'd love to get **a link to some good MS documentation** or **failing that the thoughts of an ASP.NET all star.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx)

[ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx), section "Compilation Life Cycle"